# Can we take ISTQB exam Foundation Level with version 2011 even if version 2018 is available?

Tags: istqb

When we prepare for ISTQB exam Foundation Level with version 2011 then a new version 2018 becomes available just before the exam.What shall we do? Shall I reschedule the exam and prepare 2018 or I can take it with old version?
Thanks.

Comment: What is level of exam you are writing? Foundation or Advanced?

Comment: foundation level

Comment: I update my question @Prasannavenkatesh by adding the exam level, sorry for not putting that from the beginning

Comment: Hi I want to write ISTQB foundation Level Exam.Now 2018 version is Available .Which version is preferable to take the test.Please kindly help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can take it still. Looking at [istqb.org](https://www.istqb.org/downloads/syllabi/foundation-level-syllabus.html), there are two links to the 2011 and 2018 syllabus, where the updates a listed on Page 3:

> - **[12-June-2017]** Alpha review release - Certified Tester Foundation Level Syllabus Major Update 2018 – see Appendix C – Release
>     Notes
> - **[22-November-2017]** Alpha review 2.0 release – Certified Tester Foundation Level Syllabus Major Update 2018 – see Appendix C – Release
>     Notes for details
> - **[9-December-2017]** Alpha review 2.5 release – Technical edit of 2.0 release, no new content added
> - **[15-January-2018]** Pre-cross-review internal version 2.9, incorporating Core Team edits.
> - **[19-January-2018]** Cross-review internal version 3.0.
> - **[12-February-2018]** Candidate beta version
> - **[27-April-2018]** Candidate general release version

So according to their revision history, there have been two major updates since 2011, and the [press release](https://www.istqb.org/documents/pr/ISTQB-releases-CTFL2018.pdf) stated that:

> This 2018 syllabus has more emphasis on reviews and less on test
>   management, compared with our 2011 version. We have reduced the number
>   of K1 learning objectives from 27 to 15 to focus less on remembering
>   and more on being able to apply knowledge.,” says Klaus Olsen, ISTQB®
>   Foundation working group chair.

... and so you could argue that they aren't that major in the grand scheme of things.

If you've been studying for the 2011 version, then you have until June 2019 to take it... before it gets replaced with the 2018 version. Personally, I would keep to your current exam and sit the 2011 paper - good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your clarification and your opinion, me too i prefer to not take risk and not lose more time to take the exam 2011 version then i will learn what changes are, but i'm wondering if one day people who have the ISTQB certification 2011 are obliged to pass 2018 or recent versions and the certification will be out of effect?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can take up your exam as per your **schedule**. As per the [press release](https://www.istqb.org/documents/pr/ISTQB-releases-CTFL2018.pdf) from ISTQB this 2011 syllabus has the validity upto June 2019 for all English language exams.

This 2018 syllabus has following updates in terms of software development

- Agile methods
- Continuous Integration/Continuous Delivery
- Delivery pipelines
- IoT

Have a little knowledge on these topics before taking upto the exams. It will be useful for you to have a better knowledge on these topics for your career.

Comment: yeah i have knowledge in those topics but if i pass ISTQB 2011 ; the certification still available forever or it should be updated after a period ?

Comment: Yes. It is valid. Foundation and Advances certifications has life time validity. Expert level certificate has valid upto 5 years.

Comment: Great ! thanks this is the most important thing ;)