# Taking 2018 ISTQB exam

Tags: istqb, certification

I was preparing for taking the 2011 ISTQB CTFL exam, using Brian Hambling's "Software Testing: An ISTQB-BCS Certified Tester Foundation guide".

It is possible to take the 2011 version up to June of 2019, and my exam was supposed to happen in April/May.

But now it has been postponed to mid-June and I need to take the 2018 version.

Does anyone have experience on what is the difference and if it is enough to prepare for the exam using the abovementioned text-book even for the 2018 Syllabus test?

**EDIT:**

According to Adam Roman's "A Study Guide to the ISTQB Foundation Level 2018 Syllabus", main differences between the syllabi are:

- Fewer K1 Learning Objectives in general
- Less focus on Chapter 5 Test Management
- More emphasis on review
- Static Analysis by Tools sections is removed
- More emphasis on test techniques in Chapter 4.
- White box techniques downgraded (whatever that means)

Comment: Related: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/34372/can-we-take-istqb-exam-foundation-level-with-version-2011-even-if-version-2018-i

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you do not use original source - ISTQB.org page to find this out?
Here are all differences with details: https://www.istqb.org/certification-path-root/foundation-level-2018.html
If that is not enough then here in download are you find all relevant information:https://www.istqb.org/downloads/category/51-ctfl2018.html
Pay attention to last two pdf's: "CTFL 2018 Release Notes 2 - Traceability from 2011 to 2018 on LO level"   and "CTFL 2018 Release Notes CTFL 2018 Release Notes 3 - Deleted LO from 2011 Syllabus". LO stands for Learning Objective.

If you prefer to write based on 2011, I am sure that there are certification centres in Zagreb, Croatia and you should be able to schedule and write your exam. You also can ask any training provider to write exam only. I did quick search and found several companies who offer trainings in Zagreb.

Comment: Please, read more carefully. I asked if someone has experience with studying for the 2011 version exam and taking 2018 one instead. And about the schedule, it is not up to me, my company has fixed spots for me and some co-workers.

Comment: @MateMrše You cannot learn for 2011 and write exam based on 2018 and I linked all the differences which explains why not. In you description you did not write about company schedule. You wrote that it is postponed. I wanted to be helpful and show you that there are different options.

Answer (score 1):

I have a colleague of mine completed 2018 version of the syllabus and cleared the certification. I helped her recently since I can provide you some bullet points about it.
Don'ts:

- Do not blindly go behind dumps-none of the answers correct from dumps and some questions itself do not provide clear contexts and most of the dumps are outdated or based on previous syllabus version
- Do not copy and memorize the points from any training programs since the questions are asked with implementation point of view in testing projects
- Do not think that more questions will be asked in differences of (2018 version-2011 version) since each question has weightage points for chapter-wise division.

Do's (Few Months Before Exam):

- Focus on precise practice using free materials in internet (avoid spammy contents).
  Example: https://www.guru99.com/component/com_joomlaquiz/Itemid,1187/quiz_id,18/view,quiz/
- Listen to nice youtube videos on the course content (but don't limit yourself thinking that thats all the preparation required.)
  Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TnUhrFSQd1o
- Attend some reputed training programs (whichever cheaper and avoid going through udemy practice tests since some answers were wrong in practice tests)
  Example: https://engineers-hub.teachable.com/
- Search in linkedin with queries to find recent test takers and connect them to clarify few points about exam and what kind of complexity the questions are being asked
  Example Query: #istqb #istqbcertified

Do's (Few Days Before Exam):

- Download ISTQB cheat sheets which will be handy to prepare before exam schedule
  Example (related to TAE of ISTQB): https://cheatography.com/narayanan-palani/cheat-sheets/istqb-test-automation-engineering/
- Try clearing or attempting two mock tests minimum before the exam timing.

Please keep me posted if you got some better points then me. So I can make a note of it for my next advanced level certification in ISTQB. Hope these points help you preparing for 2018 syllabus